# Apply a shapeAppearance style to a PopupMenu

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

I am using the latest version of the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
Currently it is:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09
```

According to [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#supported-components) it is possible to customize the component shapes using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in the style.
These components should be supported:

- Bottom Sheet
- Button
- Floating Action Button
- Card
- Chip
- Dialog
- Menu
- Text Field

I am able to apply the attribute to these components except the [Menu](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md), in particular `PopupMenu`. I was looking for it in the material themes but I didn't find it.
I tried something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
  <!-- Popup Menu -->
  <style name="Widget.MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.PopupMenu</item>   
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Please file an issue on the repo page if you can